# How do I clear a user's cached Active Directory password on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, ldap, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I built a CentOS 7 install on my company laptop and configured it to authenticate to the company AD servers like so:

- Install packages:

  ```
  yum install sssd realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common samba-common-tools krb5-workstation openldap-clients policycoreutils-python
  ```
- Add AD servers to `/etc/hosts`.
- Join realm:

  ```
  realm join --user=tech adserver.example.com
  realm permit -g activedirectorygroup@domain
  ```
- Change `use_fully_qualified_names` to `False` and `fallback_homedir` to `/home/%u` in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.
- Restart daemons:

  ```
  systemctl restart sssd && systemctl daemon-reload
  ```
- Setup ITGROUP to be able to use sudo:

  ```
  echo "%ITGROUP  ALL=(ALL)  ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/ITGROUP
  ```

Everything has been working fine.  ...until I changed my password on my Windows 10 PC.  In fact, the CentOS box is letting me, but just with the *old* password.  I've done a bunch of Googling and tried a bunch of things (e.g., `sss_cache -E`, `kdestroy -A`), but I can't seem to flush the cache so I can use my *new* password.

So, how do I clear a user's cached Active Directory password on CentOS 7?  Is there a way for a "regular" user to do that themselves (in case we wanted to roll this out to other systems)?

### Update:

I tried some of the suggestions, but the laptop wouldn't forget the old credentials.  I ended up removing the PC from the realm and re-adding it.  I did add this to my sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
...
account_cache_expiration = 2
cached_auth_timeout = 3600
refresh_expired_interval = 4050

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_credentials_expiration = 2
```

The login seems to be caching the AD stuff, but it tells me `Authenticated with cached credentials, your cached password will expire at:` now when I login or sudo.  I'm hoping that next time my password expires and I change it, this system will recognize it.  FYI, my whole config is:

```
[sssd]
domains = adserver.example.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/adserver.example.com]
ad_domain = adserver.example.com
krb5_realm = adserver.example.com
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = activedirectorygroup@adserver.example.com
account_cache_expiration = 2
cached_auth_timeout = 3600
refresh_expired_interval = 4050

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_credentials_expiration = 2
```

### Update #2:

I've been using this configuration for quite some time now.  I've increased the `account_cache_expiration` and `offline_credentials_expiration` from `2` to `4`, but it's been working so well we've begun using this setup on our servers.

Comment: Are you able to login with a new user on the CentOS7 machine?

Comment: Do you have an entry for `entry_cache_timeout` in your `sssd.conf`? The default is 5400 seconds, which means that every user, group, password, etc. record is re-requested from the upstream provider every hour and a half.

Comment: I do not have an `entry_cache_timeout` line in my config so it should be using the default.

Comment: I would recommend removing the `offline_credentials_expiration` line from your config. That line seems to be responsible for the `Authenticated with cached credentials` message. I removed it, reset my password in ADUC and logged in again with the new password without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how do I clear a user's cached Active Directory password on CentOS 7?

Generally `sss_cache` should be the right way to tell sssd to re-retrieve objects it has probably already cached. But afaik sssd does indeed use the cached objects again if nothing could be retrieved from the AD.

You should always be able to reset cached credentials by setting

```
[domain/your-domain.tld]
...
cache_credentials = False
```

in the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf, restarting the sssd service and reauthenticating with your user. This way you should be able to determine if authentication over SSSD/AD works at all. To check if the complete setup is working with the current settings (without using any caches), it's always a good thing to actually **delete** all caches. See the info at the bottom for how to do that most effectively.

> Is there a way for a "regular" user to do that themselves (in case we wanted to roll this out to other systems)?

I don't know how this could be safely implemented. Imho this is nothing what you want. But it shouldn't be necessary anyway. SSSD should always re-evaluate his cached credentials based on some conditions.

Most of the time it's a good idea to set the following to force re-evaluation after some days and to actually notice if something with environment is going wrong

```
[pam]
...
offline_credentials_expiration
```

as per default `offline_credentials_expiration` is set to `0` (No limit)

---

Most of the time when i want to be sure, there are no more caches in use, i do the following

```
systemctl stop sssd
rm /var/lib/sssd/db/*
systemctl start sssd
```

This can lead to a non-working sssd setup (but only if something is wrong with its setup, as all data sssd holds are simply re-retrievable from the AD).

Comment: The location where you want to delete the cache contents is actually: `/var/lib/sss/db`.

Comment: I tried you suggestion of adding `cache_credentials = false` and restarting sssd and removing the `db` files, but nothing I tried would make it "forget" the old password.